# Git difftool not working on diffing two branches

Tags: git, diff, meld, git-difftool

Im trying to diff 2 branches with the

`git difftool master..presentation`

Command. I tried both Meld and vsdiffmerge but for some reason they're not working. All the command does is repeatedly asking me if I want to diff the file with the current difftool. If I enter 'y' its opening the corresponding program and thats it, no actual diff is happening. In Meld, it simply shows the start screen with the 3 options and in Visual Studio its showing me the default window with no code tabs opened.

This is my current .gitconfig:

```
[diff]
    tool = meld
[difftool "vsdiffmerge"]
    cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/Common7/IDE/vsDiffMerge.exe' $LOCAL $REMOTE
    prompt = false
    trustExitCode = true
[difftool "meld"]
    cmd = 'A:/Development-Tools/Meld/Meld.exe'
    prompt = false
```

Please note that vsDiffMerge works fine when doing a merge, its just not working for diffs.

Just using the console diff

```
git diff master..presentation
```

Works perfectly fine.

Im using the most recent version of Git, Meld and Visual Studio.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Either add arguments to you commands (not sure if this works):

```
[difftool "meld"]
    cmd = 'A:/Development-Tools/Meld/Meld.exe $LOCAL $MERGED $REMOTE'
    prompt = false
```

Or specify the `path` of the diff tool instead of the `cmd` configuration variable:

```
[difftool "meld"]
    path = 'A:/Development-Tools/Meld/Meld.exe'
    prompt = false
```

See the [git-difftool](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) doc.